# Problem creating my own type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

So I'm trying to define my own tree type in haskell, but I'm getting an error.

```
data GTree a = Node a [Gtree a] deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

results in

> ```
> Not in scope: type constructor or class `Gtree'
> ```
>
> Failed, modules loaded: none.

I'm not sure why my definition doesn't work while the one below will...

```
data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

If anybody could explain this to me, it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition doesn't work because of the change in capitalization.  See `GTree` vs `Gtree`.

Comment: haha oh wow, I don't know how I missed that... Maybe I need to take a little break or something. Thank you very much.